# U-boot ethaddr is not set during the first time bootup of Linux kernel

Tags: ethernet, u-boot

I have two boards from the different vendor, in which the first one works well other board with Macronix flash memory fails to detect the ethaddrr.

EDIT: My hardware info:

```
Working Hw:     Micoron 512MB Nor flash, AR; 32-bit 
Not working Hw: Macronix 512 MB(MX29GL256F) NOR Flash, ARM 32 bit.
```

I checked there is not `ethaddr` in my env variable. I checked in my working board I have `ethaddr` variable `ethaddr=00:01:02:03:04:54` .

I tried to set the ethaddr/mac-id as 00:01:02:03:04:55 using `setenv` and `saveenv` but this doesn't work.

I checked my u-boot config also.

```
#define CONFIG_NET_MULTI        1
```

My question is, ethaddr/mac-id is more Hw specific why don't it detects ethddr in certain boards?

**This is my error info :**

```
U-Boot 2010.09 (Apr 16 2018 - 10:59:13)
DRAM:  32 MiB
Flash: 32 MiB
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   macb0
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Checking firmware at 0x100e0000-0x107fffff
  invalid magic 0xffff, ignoring
Checking firmware at 0x10820000-0x10f3ffff
  invalid magic 0xffff, ignoring
highest = 0
No valid firmware in flash, trying to load kernel and ramdisk from server
macb0: PHY present at 0
macb0: Starting autonegotiation...
macb0: Autonegotiation complete
macb0: link up, 100Mbps full-duplex (lpa: 0xcde1)
*** ERROR: `ethaddr' not set
macb0: PHY present at 0
macb0: link up, 100Mbps full-duplex (lpa: 0xcde1)
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

Comment: Please provide more information such as what hardware you're on as well as the full boot log.  And then, most likely, try again with mainline CONFIG_NET_MULTI has been meaningless for a long time now.  Thanks!

Comment: @TomRini, that is the full bootlog, kernel is not loading via tftpboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever set MAC addresses just out of the blue. Kernel is not picking it up because your MAC address has multicast bit set.

See http://www.denx.de/wiki/bin/view/DULG/EthernetDoesNotWork

If you want to set a local MAC address you need to make sure it's valid.  U-BOOT you can do that by using

```
$ make tools/gen_eth_addr
cc     tools/gen_eth_addr.c   -o tools/gen_eth_addr
$ tools/gen_eth_addr
ba:d0:4a:9c:4e:ce
```

See http://www.denx.de/wiki/bin/view/DULG/WhereCanIGetAValidMACAddress for details.

Also this is not a kernel programming problem so it really doesn't belong here.

Comment: thanks for the info. I m wondering why certain boards have empty MAC address. Is that gen_ethr_addr ethaddr is just for the local test only right?

Comment: gen_ethr_addr is alright for locally administratable MAC addresses -- "addresses are distinguished by setting the second least significant bit of the most significant byte of the address".  Don't do something silly :-) like use the same address on cross exposed networks.

Comment: Boards have empty MAC addresses so that you can test them with your own block.